# componentsByString for NSMutableSet in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, nsset, nsmutableset

I have label and NSMutable Set.

I want to assign my set value to label.text.

```
  @IBOutlet var location: UILabel!
 var mutSet:NSMutableSet = NSMutableSet()

        self.location.text = **mutSet.allObjects.componetsJoinedByString("\n")**
```

mutSet.allObjects.componetsJoinedByString("\n") throws compile time error
similarly I have tried joined , it also throws compile time error.

Please provide me alternative way in Swift

Comment: If you look at the compiler error it will give you a hint.

Comment: *compone**n**ts*. Why `NSMutableSet` at all? Use native Swift `Set`.

Comment: Sorry,It didnt provide hint. same thing working in Objective C but not in swift

Comment: I have chosen NSMutableSet because I have to add String and Array of String  to NSMutableSet.  Native set is not allowing me add the String and Array of String

Comment: allObjects returns [Any] not [String] so the compiler can’t send it a message for a string. swift is stricter about this than Objective-C

Comment: That's not true. You can add string and array of string. See my answer.

Comment: The NSMutableSet() that the OP is using doesn't work the same way as in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all to answer your question: You have to write

```
(mutSet.allObjects as! [String]).joined(separator: "\n")
```

`NS(Mutable)Set` lacks any type information. You have to cast the type to actual `[String]`

---

It's highly recommended to use native `Set` and generally you are discouraged from using `NSMutable...` types if there is a native counterpart.

```
var mutSet = Set<String>(["a", "b", "c"])
```

You can append (actually `insert`) an item - a set is unordered

```
mutSet.insert("d")
```

or an array of items

```
mutSet.formUnion(["c", "d", "f"])
```

Joining is much shorter than in Foundation `NSMutableSet`

```
mutSet.joined(separator: "\n")
```

or sorted joined

```
mutSet.sorted().joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you  for the solution

Comment: Thank them by accepting their answer! Click the tick.